# Split string after every second occurence of unknown element

Tags: python, string, split, polygon

I have a string with list of coordinates which represents polygons.
In this list each polygon have starting and ending coordinates which are the same.
I need to have each polygon in separate string (or list).

*'**17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875**,17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984,17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672,**17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875**,
**28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094**,28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285,28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156, **28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094**'*

So from this simple example I need to have two elements:

One = '**17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875**,17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984,17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672,**17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875**'

Two = '**28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094**,28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285,28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156, **28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094**'*

There can be more polygons in string each needs to be separated.
I can use only standard python libraries for this

Comment: Bolded ones are same points for each polygons (start/end)

Comment: Oh someone please format it. I'm in a hurry

Comment: I think it's formatted fine once it's explained what bold means.

Comment: @Bazingaa The OP has actually formatted it very carefully.  I tried to, and rapidly rolled back!

Comment: The first 2 coordinates in the string are not separated by a comma. Is this correct?

Comment: Where's the difficulty, you read the first pair and scan until it reappears ?

Comment: Yes, each pair is separated by comma.

Comment: Sometimes they are separated by a comma and a space instead...

Comment: Space separates coordinates X and Y, comma separates pairs (vertices). So element here is pair of coordinates not one coordinate.

Comment: My comment still stands. Sometimes the separator is `,`, sometimes it's `, `. I don't know if this was an error in your question or something that requires handling.

Comment: An edit error. Comma without white space is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly ugly but working solution, just putting the obvious approach into code really.

```
# Note that your string has inconsistent separators -- sometimes ',', sometimes ', '.
# I'm going to separate on `,` and not worry about it -- you need to work out
# what the correct separator is.
s = '17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875,17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984,17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672,17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094,28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285,28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094'

coordinates = s.split(',')

polygon = []
polygons = []

new = True

for coordinate in coordinates:
    polygon.append(coordinate)

    if new:
        start = coordinate
        new = False

    elif coordinate == start:
        polygons.append(polygon)
        polygon = []
        new = True

result = [",".join(polygon) for polygon in polygons]
print(result)

Out:
['17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875,17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984,17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672,17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875', ' 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094,28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285,28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094']
```

Comment: I don't think we'll escape "ugly" on this one :)

Answer (score 2):

```
s='17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875,17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984,17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672,17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094,28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285,28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094'

#convert the input in a list of points 
coordinates = [tuple(map(float,el.split())) for el in s.split(",")]

polygons = []

#find the polygons
while coordinates:
    ind = coordinates[1:].index(coordinates[0]) 
    polygons.append(coordinates[0:ind+2])
    coordinates = coordinates[ind+2:]

#output
[(17.17165756225586, -28.102264404296875), (17.184370040893555, -28.200496673583984), (17.1986083984375, -28.223613739013672), (17.17165756225586, -28.102264404296875)]
[(28.865726470947266, -28.761619567871094), (28.80694007873535, -28.75750160217285), (28.792499542236328, -28.706947326660156), (28.865726470947266, -28.761619567871094)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your input is already a string (and your expected result also?), you can try this super-lazy solution using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) `(([^,]+).*\2)` with backreferences. Here, `[^,]+` is the first coordinate pair, `.*` the other pairs, and `\2` the first pair again.

```
>>> s = '17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875,17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984,17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672,17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094,28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285,28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094'
>>> re.findall(r"(([^,]+).*\2)", s)
[('17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875,17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984,17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672,17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875',
  '17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875'),
 (' 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094,28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285,28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094',
  ' 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094')]
```

Or use `finditer` and get the `group` to get a list of strings directly:

```
>>> [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r"(([^,]+).*\2)", s)]
['17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875,17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984,17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672,17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875',
 ' 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094,28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285,28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094']
```

After some post-processing, to get the actual lists of pairs of numbers (with `_` being the result of `findall`; for `finditer` drop the `[0]`):

```
>>> [[tuple(map(float, y.split())) for y in x[0].split(",")] for x in _]
[[(17.17165756225586, -28.102264404296875),
  (17.184370040893555, -28.200496673583984),
  (17.1986083984375, -28.223613739013672),
  (17.17165756225586, -28.102264404296875)],
 [(28.865726470947266, -28.761619567871094),
  (28.80694007873535, -28.75750160217285),
  (28.792499542236328, -28.706947326660156),
  (28.865726470947266, -28.761619567871094)]]
```

For longer strings, this may not be the fastest solution, I did not time it, though.

Comment: Nice, I came up with `r'(([\-\d\. ]+).*?\2)'`, 15 minutes too late. Is there any possibility to get a list of strings directly instead of a list of tuples of strings?

Comment: Is seems to work, will have to test it on string with more polygons.

Comment: @EricDuminil I tried with non-capturing groups, but using `findall` this seems to be the only way. You could also use `[m.group() for m in re.finditer(...)]` though to get just a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting your long string with every "," and puttting it into an array. Then make a for loop and do:

```
intStart = 0;
if (array[intStart] == array[i]){
    for(j=0; j<i; j++){
        string += array[j];
    }
    arrPolygons.push(string);
    intStart = i+1;
}
```

So when the starting coordinates match a value, add all variables between those values to a string. Then push string to another array. Then start comparing the next value to data after.

By the way this is just a pseudo code example.

Hope this helps

Comment: Why are you posting an answer in another language? If anything, this just confuses the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875,17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984,17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672,17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094,28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285,28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094'

coord = s.split(',')

inpoly = False
poly = [[]]
start = None
for i in coord:
    poly[-1].append(i)
    if i == start:
        poly.append([])
        inpoly = False
    if not inpoly:
        start = i
        inpoly = True

print(poly)
```

Output:

```
[['17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875', '17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984', '17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672', '17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875'], [' 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094', '28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285', '28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156', ' 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094']]
```

Answer (score 0):

input data...

```
lst = [
    '17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875',
    '17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984',
    ...
    '17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672',
    '17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875',
    '28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094',
    ...
    '28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285',
    '28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156',
    '28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094',
]

lst1 = []
for cord in lst:
    if cord not in lst1:
        lst1.append(cord)
print(lst1)
```

output:

```
[
    '17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875',
    '17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984',
    '17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672',
    '28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094',
    '28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285',
    '28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156',
    '28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094',
]
```

Comment: This completely misses the mark. You haven't made pairs of coordinates or split the list, you've just filtered it in a way that isn't meaningful

Answer (score 0):

I really like @newbie's solution in its conciseness. Here is a slightly more verbose/readable one:

```
s = '17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875,17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984,17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672,17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094,28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285,28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094'
vertices = [c.strip() for c in s.split(",")] # split and clean vertex data

polygons = []           
current_polygon = None

for vertex in vertices:
    if current_polygon is None:             # start a new polygon
        current_polygon = [vertex]
    elif current_polygon[0] == vertex:      # conclude the current polygon
        current_polygon.append(vertex)
        polygons.append(current_polygon)
        current_polygon = None
    else:                                   # continue the current polygon
        current_polygon.append(vertex)

for polygon in polygons:    # print polygons
    print(",".join(polygon))
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach:

```
def split_polygons(s):
    if s == '':  # base case
        return []
    start, rest = s.split(',', 1)
    head, tail = map(lambda x: x.strip(', '), rest.split(start, 1))
    poly = start + ',' + head + start  # reconstruct the first polygon
    return [poly] + split_polygons(tail)
```

---

```
>>> p = '17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875,17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984,17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672,17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094,28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285,28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094'
>>> split_polygons(p)
['17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875,17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984,17.1986083984375 -28.22361373901367217.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875', '28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094,28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285,28.792499542236328 -28.70694732666015628.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c = '17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875,17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984,\
    17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672,17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875,\
    28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094,28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285,\
    28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156, 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094'

c = [i.strip(' ') for i in c.split(',')]
i = 0
lst = []

while i!=len(c):
    out = c[i]    
    j = i+1

    while c[i]!=c[j]:
        out = out+','+c[j]
        j = j+1

    out = out+','+c[j]
    lst.append(out)
    out=''
    i = j+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, this approach applies to any string length as far as it will be based on the input format that you gave.

```
strng = "17.17165756225586,-28.102264404296875,17.184370040893555,-28.200496673583984,17.1986083984375,-28.223613739013672,17.17165756225586,-28.102264404296875,28.865726470947266,-28.761619567871094,28.80694007873535,-28.75750160217285,28.792499542236328,-28.706947326660156,28.865726470947266,-28.761619567871094"
#convert to list of tuples
l_tuple = zip(*[iter(strng.split(','))]*2)
#get list of duplicate indexes
l_index=[]
for Tuple in l_tuple:
    x = [i for i,x in enumerate(l_tuple) if x == Tuple]
    if len(x)>1:
        l_index.append(x)
#get separate lists
New_list = []
for IND in list(set(map(tuple,l_index))):
    print(l_tuple[IND[0]:IND[1]+1])
    New_list.append(l_tuple[IND[0]:IND[1]+1])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> lst = ['17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875','17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984',\
... '17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672','17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875',' 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094',\
... '28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285','28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156', '28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094']

>>> lst1 =[]
>>> for cord in lst:
...    if cord not in lst1:
...         lst1.append(cord)
... 
>>> print(lst1)
['17.17165756225586 -28.102264404296875', '17.184370040893555 -28.200496673583984', '17.1986083984375 -28.223613739013672', ' 28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094', '28.80694007873535 -28.75750160217285', '28.792499542236328 -28.706947326660156', '28.865726470947266 -28.761619567871094']
```